# Скрипт на PHP перестал искать сравнение введёных данных с данными в БД. Почему?

Tags: php, pdo

У меня есть PHP скрипт:

```
<?php
$username = filter_var(trim($_POST['username']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

include ('cannectBack.php');

$pass = md5($pass. 'hdisdidisdi13sadsd555');

$sth = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `sistem` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
$mazer = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($mazer) == 0) {
    echo header("Location: errorLogin.html");
    exit();
}

setcookie('user', $user['username'], time() + 3600, "/" );
header("Location: userjdjw9eqi3dwojdojsdcm033.php");
?>
```

Он раньше искал сравнение с введеными данными в БД, потом я переписал скрипт для PDO, после всё нормально работало и тут вдруг раз и он перестал работать, чтобы я не вводили он все равно пропускает и не выводит ошибку. Может что-то с Cookie? Я новечёк в этом деле и немного не понимаю что случилось.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Вот прям так работало работало и РАААААААЗ перестало?

Comment: Да, я проверял много раз.

Comment: А где вас учили так делать - вот это вот всё: `filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`, `WHERE username = '$username'`? За такое ведь сейчас выгоняют из профессии

Comment: и как бы да - ну вы определитесь, что у вас не работает - "сравнение с БД" или "перестало пускать"

Comment: Сравнение с БД, мне не нравится что меня пропускает в любом случяи, а должно пропускать если пароль и логин правильный.

Comment: Для того, чтобы перестало пускать, надо посмотреть, что лежит в "$mazer" и подумать, что вы хотите получать, применяя к этой переменной функцию count()

Comment: echo header() неверная конструкция https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header